# Can company page accounts create apps?

Tags: facebook

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Creating and managing a Facebook app from a Business Account](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10805745/creating-and-managing-a-facebook-app-from-a-business-account)

I don't seem to be able to access the developer section for apps, I was able to create a new facebook app a few days ago by visiting https://developers.facebook.com/apps while logged in is the main company account.

However, I seem to be getting redirected back to our company page every time I try to access our apps?  Looking at the response I seem to be getting:

```
GET https;//developers.facebook.com/apps
302 redirect to https;//www.facebook.com/upgradeaccount.php
302 redirect to https;//www.facebook.com/business/dashboard/
302 redirect to https;//www.facebook.com/pages/manage
302 redirect to https;//www.facebook.com/organisation
```

If I visit https://developers.facebook.com/apps when not logged in it asks me to log in, then confirm my password, then sends me right back to my homepage.

Is this by design?

(PS, I've used ; in the URLs to get around my new reputation)

Comment: Hey! Why was it closed?
I have the very same issue! But 2 weeks earlier I create an app, it was working fine. But today I wanted to change app image and could not access https://developers.facebook.com/apps

Comment: Hi - I'm facing the same problem. How are businesses supposed to create apps?

Comment: This seems more like a question for Facebook Support, unless you believe there is a problem with your code.

Comment: See also http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/8434865

Comment: For reference it seems that the answer is no, there are two types of accounts: personal accounts and business accounts.  A business account is heavily restricted, in order to do anything useful you have to assign an administrator to the business account.  The administrator (a personal account) can create and assign apps etc.   My issue is that I had to use my own personal account to administer our company's business account, apps are created in my account and assigned to our business account through my role as administrator.  As you can imagine, this _will_ cause headaches in the future.